# Linear model - variable many zeros

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am building a linear model where one of the predictors is zero almost all the time. After building the model, the variable is significant and has a huge parameter estimate.

By my understanding, the variable is meaningful and should stay in the model, but I was told (by my teacher) that I need to do something with this variable.
Do I need to transform the data? Or make the variable factorial (which makes the parameter estimate even bigger).

I've looked at other questions (eg. [Explanatory variables with many zeros](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62485/explanatory-variables-with-many-zeros)), but this is just a question about why would we do something.
For example: this is a model about forest fires with the response variable Area. The variable Rain is significant, but is zero except in 6 of the 517 observations. I just kept Rain in the model as a continuous variable and it had a big parameter estimate. The remark I got is that the rain parameter is too sensitive to interpret (Why is this? and is this a good reason te delete this variable? or are there other possibilities or explanations?)
The teachers also said that the variable rain might be explained by another variable, but what are the consequences of this? And how can I check whether there is such a relation between the Rain variable and another variable?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you explain how this problem is different than other questions about zeroes in the predictors/regressors/explanatory variables/independent variables? For example: [Explanatory variables with many zeros](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62485/explanatory-variables-with-many-zeros)

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. However, like the linked post, it still isn't entirely clear to me what you are doing. If the response variable is area, then are you performing a classification task? Whether "rain" is explained by another variable is not something that can be answered without knowing what you are modeling and what those other variables are. Could you include a research question and a description of the data (or an excerpt)?